# how run Laravel 5.5 project without localhost:8000 url?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

> how run Laravel 5.5 project without localhost:8000 url?

---

my project name **lms_manager**
I want to load my project without **localhost:8000** and **php artisan serve** command url and I want to load it **localhost/lms_manager** but I really don't know how do it,

please can I help?

Comment: You should understand how to set up apache or nginx vhost (virtual host). Find and read articles about it.

Comment: why not `http://lmsmanager.com` ? It looks real

Comment: `localhost/lms_manager/public`

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some changes

**1st**  : move `lms_manager\public\index.php` to main folder `lms_manager\index.php`

**2nd** : Change path in `index.php` you just moved, from

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

To

```
require __DIR__.'\bootstrap\autoload.php'; In Windows
```

Or

```
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php'; In Linux
```

I assume you folder is inside htdocs so that you can run `localhost/lms_manager`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do these changes on your files:

1) Goto *C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc* and write this in **hosts** file

```
 127.0.0.1       lms_manager.com (choose whatever name you like)
```

2)Goto *C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra* and write this in **httpd-vhosts.conf** file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/lms_manager/public"
    ServerName lms_manager.com
</VirtualHost>
```